# Jquery input append element doesnt send value

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have two loops in script and want to increment both counters

In first loop I am taking data from php and making incrementation (that is ok),
but in another loop I am using append from jQuery, and append create all elements, but when I click on post I can see all elements but not values ...

here is first part (where I send product ids)

```
<?php
foreach ($products as $product): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?= $this->Form->input('item_['.$product->id.']', ['id' => 'product_'.$product->id, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control']); ?></td>
    <td><?= $product->name ?></td>
    <td><?= $product->name ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then when i insert for product 1 - value 3 I have to iterate 3 times same product p[1][1], p[1][2] p[1][3] and so on for each product

here is code how I iterate that

```
j = 1;
foreach($products as $product){
var qty = parseInt($('#product_<?= $product->id ?>').val());
    for (i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
    j++
     $(wrapper).append(
'<div class="item-border" id="preselected-'+ j +'">'+
        '<div class="col-sm-6">'+
           '<label><?=__('First Name')?></label>'+
           '<input name="first_name_item_[<?=$product->id?>]['+i+']" id="first_name_item_[<?=$product->id?>]['+i+']" class="form-control first_name" value="" />'+

);
```

}

Then when I send data with post I got this

```
data => [

    'first_name_item_' => [
        (int) 1 => [
            (int) 0 => '',
            (int) 1 => ''
        ],
        (int) 2 => [
            (int) 0 => '',
            (int) 1 => ''
        ],
        (int) 3 => [
            (int) 0 => '',
            (int) 1 => ''
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Where is the `value` in `'<input name="first_name_item_[<?=$product->id?>]['+i+']" id="first_name_item_[<?=$product->id?>]['+i+']" class="form-control first_name" />'+` - also is this not PHP? `foreach($products as $product){`

Comment: Please provide the *rendered* html.

Comment: I am showing each input in html and then adding value manualy for each item then send (post)

Comment: Please create a [mcve] showing RENDERED HTML and jQuery

Comment: This `foreach(x as y)` does not look like javascript, so looks like you're mixing php and js without adding the php tags in the code in the question.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes it is mixed php and jQuery, and I am adding product ID like tax for each id + in jQuery adding incremental ID for each product to (product[PHP ID][jQuery ID]

Comment: @mplungjan here is HTML render of first name field    <div class="col-sm-6"><label>First name</label><input name="first_name_item_[2][0]" id="first_name_item_[2][0]" class="form-control first_name" value=""></div>

Comment: Kindly update your question instead of posting unformatted comments - this code is not complete: `'<input name="first_name_item_[<?=$product->id?>]['+i+']" id="first_name_item_[<?=$product->id?>]['+i+']" class="form-control first_name" />'+`